# rsync local file system to remote automatically on file change, windows to unix

Tags: windows, unix, ssh

Our team currently works, on macs pushing file changes via rsync to freeBSD with our editor being Komodo

1 - User saves file
2 - Macro in Komodo runs and rsync command to sync the local directory to the remote

```
var rsyncCommand = "rsync -av --delete --filter=";
rsyncCommand += "':- .gitignore'";
rsyncCommand += " ";
rsyncCommand += "/local/ezpublish_git/"
rsyncCommand += " ";
rsyncCommand += "john@mydomain.com:/remote/dir/ezpublish_git/";
```

ko.run.runEncodedCommand(window, rsyncCommand);

The rsync command works as each machine has an ssh key setup.

On a windows machine we found a windows equivalent to rsync called cwrsync, which in theory should do the exact same but I am having troubles getting the Windows machine to connect to the remote via ssh using an ssh key. Each post I find about automatically connected to a remote unix box from windows via ssh says use PuTTY. This is not great as Komodo runs the windows command line not through putty.

So how can i get windows to automatically connect to a unix box via ssh with ssh keys without using PuTTY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem may be that other clients using rsync don't explicitely pass a parameter, specifying tunneling through ssh, or the location of the private key, to rsync, as on those systems, the key is usually placed in a preconfigured location, usually in directory .ssh of users' home directory where ssh can find it.
This is probably not the case with ssh from cwRsync.

You may need to specify both with cwRsync:

- create a new SSH key pair without a passphrase, using ssh-keygen (there is a copy in the bin\ directory of your cwRsync installation). Copy it to an appropriate location.
- add to rsync options: -e "ssh -i private-key"

rsync and ssh should also be in the bin\ directory.

Comment: ahhh.. ok. So would "private-key" be the location of the key on my hdd, eg C:\Users\John\.ssh\id_rsa.pub  ?

Comment: Almost.  "yes" for "location of key", but not the id_rsa.pub - that's the public key, which needs to be addeded to the authorized_keys file on remote server. Your private key should come without the .pub ending

Comment: OK, so add location ie: -e "ssh -i c:\User\John\.ssh"  great i will give this a try. Thanks for the help.

Comment: still not quite. You have two keys, forming a key pair. A public key, id_rsa.pub, and a private key, id_rsa. You'd specify name and location of the private key.